# PHP - How to store a large number of filepaths to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, store, filepath

I need to store a very large number of files to a MySQL database. These files are stored on the server, and what I need to do is something like this:

```
ID     artist         album         path
123    Artist Name    Album Name    /music/Artist Name/Album Name/Music Name.mp3
```

But as I said, it's a very large number of files, and add them manually isn't an option. I'm wondering if anyone knows an easy way for me to import at least the path into the database. The Artist and Album I can implement after, and it's possible to do it manually.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write php script which will read files from specific location. You can use directory iterator http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php
2. Form text file with structure 'artist_name' 'album' 'path'.
3. Use LOAD DATA INFILE 'file' INTO TABLE your_table; See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

A clue: Use PHP to recursively look through your file structure for *.mp3 files, or whichever the extensions you are looking for. For each result returned, store the whole path, filesize etc. in the database table. You might want to consider using Python language for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create db table with those fields.
2. Google for a php script that gets the list of directories/subdirectories/filenames.
3. Store that info in DB.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe need something like this:

```
$files = scandir(...); // you need scandir recursively the path /music

foreach($files as $file) {
    $paths  = explode("/", $file);

    $artist = $paths[1];
    $album  = $paths[2];

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO table (artist, album, path) VALUES ('$artist', '$album', '$file');";
    // execute sql or save it into file...
}
```